# Get the value of input when the cursor is out in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a input :

```
<a-form-item label="user" :colon="false">
    <a-input placeholder="user" name="user" @keyup.enter="checkUser"/>
</a-form-item>
```

In methods:

```
checkUser() {
   console.log('ok');
},
```

In methods : `checkUser` when i enter then i get the input value. But now I don't want to do that, I want when I finish entering the input value, move the cursor outside and methods : `checkUser` will get the value of that input. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `blur` event listener.

```
<a-input placeholder="user" name="user" @blur="checkUser"/>
```

**Sample Fiddle**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  methods: {
    checkUser: function(e) {
      console.log("Blur event triggered", e.target.value)
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @blur="checkUser">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the method to get triggered while moving out the cursor then you can use `@mouseleave` event.
OR
If you want to trigger the method when the input loses focus then you could try using `@blur` event

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    checkUser(e) {
      if(e.target.value !== '') { // To check if the input is not empty
        console.log("event triggered", e.target.value)
      }
      return;
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @mouseleave="checkUser">
  <!-- OR -->
  <!--<input type="text" @blur="checkUser"> -->
</div>
```

Comment: `mouseleave` doesnot have anthing to be done with the user input. If you make use of `mouseleave` event, the listner will trigger only when the user moves the cursor through the input. Even if the user moves out focus from input, the listner wont trigger.

Comment: I know, but since he asked to trigger the method while moving the cursor, I mentioned it.

Comment: @Amaarrockz Is there a way when I click on input and don't enter any value, I point the cursor out, the event won't fire

Comment: @Amaarrockz User can move in and out of an input with keyboard navigation aswell. There this code clearly breakes. Also this will keep on triggering whenever the user moves  mouse over the input. Is that acually needed?

Comment: Why are you worried if that's actually needed. The one who asked the question can decide which of the two events is best suitable for his case.

Comment: @Amaarrockz I want when the user enters the input and takes the cursor out, it will get the input value, if the user points to the input but doesn't enter anything, it will return a null result. Is there a way to when the user does not? What do I input, the event doesn't happen. I'm a js newbie so it's a bit difficult for me

Comment: @deskeay irrespective of whether the input is empty or not, the event will be fired. What you can do is place a condition checking if the empty is empty, if yes then do not execute the method's code, else proceed

Comment: Pls check the edited answer

Comment: Great, if that helped, pls feel free to upvote/accept the answer

Comment: @deskeay What is your actual requirement? Why do you want to trigger the event when the user moves the cursor through the input? Do you want to tigger event on mouse movement over the input, or while the user enters a value and moves out the focus?